Solve docutils error when querying `self.state.document.current_source` in Sphinx extension, or better way to get filepath
Consider a generic Directive as the basis for a new extension. I'll only show the code that elicits an error.
import docutils.nodes
from docutils import nodes, core
import docutils.nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive, directives
from pathlib import Path

class TestDirective(Directive):
    ''' Return the last two parts of the Path for each document that is processed. Do other cool stuff.'''

    has_content = True

    standard_include_path = Path(states.__file__).parent / 'include'

    option_spec = {'file': directives.path,
                   'url': directives.uri,
                   'encoding': directives.encoding,
                   'class': directives.class_option}
    def run(self):

        # Next line is key to solving the problem
        current_source = self.state.document.current_source
        
        # Add error handling solution here

        # Do some path manipulation
        full_filepath = Path(current_source)
        filepath_no_suffix = full_filepath.with_suffix('')
        filepath = filepath_no_suffix.parts[-2:]
        
        # View the last two parts of the file path of file being processed
        # Purpose - Build a URL path; first, print path before assigning it to a variable.

        url_path = Path(*filepath)
        print("URL",url_path)

        # Other code follows to traverse docutils.nodes and extract data.
        # [...] 


def setup(app):
    # Register custom directive
    app.add_directive("testdirective", TestDirective)


Assumptions

Items added in conf.py

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../_ext'))
testdirective was added to extensions


Using Sphinx 4.2.0
Using Python3.10
Using a custom Makefile that supports make build and make clean targets
Using a sphinx-quickstart where only 3 docs were added; used as source dir

Directory structure:
source/
guides/
overview.rst
get_started.rst
developer_guide.rst



Expected output
In summary, every line should show some "URL directory/document"
URL guides/overview7%] guides/overview
URL guides/get_started9%] guides/get_started
URL guides/developer_guide26%] guides/developer_guide

Error output
A error occurs on line 1.
This may be due to Sphinx pulling in substitutions from the rst_epilog in conf.py. I'm not sure.
URL <rst_epilog>
URL guides/get_started9%] guides/get_started
URL guides/developer_guide26%] guides/developer_guide

Error Inquiry
In the Error Output, line 1, instead of producing a filepath, it produces <rst_epilog>.
I need to code some error handling to make sure that if the builder encounters this type of message, it can revert to the parent filename.  Does anyone have any insight on how to solve this?
What I've tried
I've been hacking on including some variaton of the class Include(Directive), here: https://sphinx-docutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/docutils/parsers/rst/directives/misc.html#
So far, I tried to insert the following code where comment "Add error handling solution here" appears, but nothing works.
Example attempt to solve error:
    current_source = self.state.document.current_source
    path = directives.path(self.arguments[0])
    if path.startswith('<') and path.endswith('>'):
        _base = self.standard_include_path
        path = path[1:-1]
    else:
        _base = Path(current_source).parent
    path = utils.relative_path(None, _base/path)

Yet, if I add the above code, I receive the following error:
path = directives.path(self.arguments[0])
IndexError: list index out of range


Oh dear, I found a solution within minutes of posting. Still, I must admit, I am not satisfied with this solution because the error occurs as a result of which method one chooses to include for substitutions in the conf.py, shown below.  And Sphinx maintainers should provide error-handling for this "leaky" error.
Solution: Replace rst_epilog with rst_prolog in conf.py.
rst_epilog = """
.. include:: /substitutions.txt
"""
rst_prolog =
"""
.. |STUFF| replace:: Really cool stuff
"""
Hoping this may help another Sphinx developer in the future. :)

Your expections are wrong: document.current_source is a "Path to or description of the input source being processed." and may be a str or None. It is intended for diagnostic output and not guaranteed to hold a file path or URI. The actual output shows, that there may be parts of the source that don't originate from a file. A "Document Tree" may also be generated from string input or the standard input, so it may even happen that there is no associated source file at all. So you need to handle the case gracefully.

As a fallback, you may try the document elements "source" attribute self.state.document['source'] or the internal "_source" attribute self.state.document._source.
Similar to the internal "current_source" attribute, they may be

a file path
a URI
a formal or informal description of the source (e.g. standard input or the entity that generated a source string).
None

This means, that you also need a second fallback for the case of documents that have no associated file or URI as source.
